# EhtosDistro Error Claymore for ETH mining (libOpenCL.so.1)

Tags: mining, claymore

I'm trying use claymore for mining ETH but it get this error "/opt/miners/claymore/claymore error while loading shared libraries: libOpenCL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

I have 6 GPUs NVIDIA 1080 and EthosDistro. The config is:

## # cat /home/ethos/local.conf

globalminer claymore
maxgputemp 70
stratumproxy enabled
proxywallet 0x0750a5C3daa7eacBA912F1cA581b37Ce7c0f7B8f
proxypool1 eth-us-east1.nanopool.org:9999
proxypool2 eth-us-west1.nanopool.org:9999
flags --cl-global-work 8192 --farm-recheck 200
globalfan 80
globalcore 1847
globalmem 5524
autoreboot 1

## claymore.stub.conf

-colors 0
-dbg -1
-esm 1
-epool proxypool1 eth-us-east1.nanopool.org:9999
-ewal 0x0750a5C3daa7eacBA912F1cA581b37Ce7c0f7B8f
-epsw x
-eworker g1080-01
-allpools 1
-gser 2
-allcoins 1
-wd 0
-ethi 16